# HTML/CSS left and right div side by side on Chrome but not on Safari/Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari, alignment

I am having a hard time aligning divs side by side in Firefox and Safari, however it works great in Chrome. It is hard to give all the css because I have a mobile stylesheet, a normal one, and then the print one which is the one in question. The other stylesheets work great. If more information is needed to solve this please let me know.

My website is at http://bidonmoving.com/Template1/website.php for more details

A image of the Chrome page:
[image: http://bidonmoving.com/Resify/Resumes/Template1/images/chrome.png]

A image of the Firefox page:
[image: http://bidonmoving.com/Resify/Resumes/Template1/images/firefox.png]

My HTML setup is basically as follows:

```
<div class="page">
    <div class="content">
                    <div class="left-content"></div>
                    <div class="right-content"></div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

And the CSS is:

```
.page {
    clear:both;
    background-image: none;
    background-color:none;
    margin: 50px auto;
    margin-left:30px;
    border:0;
    outline:none;
}
.content {
    clear: both;
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 1000px;
    background: #ccc;
    position: relative;
    border:0;
    outline:0;
    -webkit-box-shadow:none;
    -webkit-box-shadow:none;
}
.left-content{
    width:450px;
    text-align:left;
}
.right-content{
    width:450px;
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:0px;
    padding-top:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
```

Comment: Not sure why you have `-webkit-box-shadow:none;` twice, or `text-align:left;`.

Comment: If I wanted to answer your question, I would have given an answer; please don't tell me what to do. Instead, I left a comment on things that help you to consider improving your code overall.

Comment: Okay, well thank you for being so kind to show a duplicate which was a simple mistake with undo that used to be -moz-box-shadow, and on my mobile css the text-align is centered so it needed to be corrected to text-align:left for it to work properly.

Comment: Try adding `position:relative` to `.left-content`

Comment: Adding a relative position made the gap a lot larger on Firefox and did not affect Chrome at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by adding a top css element to .right-content, this however made Chrome's right side go down more than it should and flipped the problem from all other browsers to just Chrome being the problem. I used a css hack to make Chrome work and from what I see it works great.

Answer (score 0):

Change your css as -

```
.left-content{
    width:450px;
    text-align:left;
    float:left;
 }
 .right-content{
    width:450px;
    float:right; (or float:left and some margin-left)
  }
```

Comment: This did not work. Can you please check out the site at http://bidonmoving.com/Template1/website.php and take a closer look?

Comment: This takes me to a 404 page

Comment: I removed that test page. I posted my solution but i cannot mark myself as the correct answer yet

Answer (score 0):

change your CSS to this

```
.left-content{
    width:450px;
    display:inline-block;
vertical-align:top;
margin-top:0px;
    padding-top:0px;
margin-right:auto;
margin-left:auto;

}
.right-content{
    width:450px;
    display:inline-block;
vertical-align:top;
    margin-top:0px;
    padding-top:0px;
margin-right:auto;
margin-left:auto;

}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to change anything. When I remove absolute from the right column it starts under the left column, but on the right side of the page.